# Compare Two Files and Remove the Duplicates

Tags: notepad++, notepad, comparison, file-comparison, file-compare

What is the easiest way to compare 2 files and deleting the duplicates found on both files. I'm aware you can do this easily on a linux box with certain commands, but how would I go about achieving this on a windows computer? I would of thought there would be a way to do this on Notepad++ but I can't seem to find one.

The other answers on here don't support a user on windows or don't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++ Compare two files and remove](https://superuser.com/questions/562208/notepad-compare-two-files-and-remove)

Comment: The methods mentioned in this post don't work because their fixes either require a linux box or simply don't work.

Comment: @holograms - If you are using Windows 10 version 1903+, you have access to WSL 2, so those Linux solutions are now native Windows solutions.  You could also use PowerShell or any number of third-party software solutions.

Comment: @Ramhound sadly i'm on windows 8

Comment: There are dozens of third-party software applications that will find and list any potential duplicate files on a system.  If the suggested solutions in the duplicate are not acceptable you should use one of those.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not looking for duplicate files, I'm looking for duplicate lines in 2 text files. If you know a software that does this please share it with me because i've looked and couldn't find one.

Comment: @holograms - Making software recommendations is against the rules.

Comment: If you have windows 10, you can use WSL and the linux commands will work natively on your windows box.  Very handy to add to your toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm aware you can do this easily on a Linux box with certain commands, but how would I go about achieving this on a Windows computer?

**GNUWin32**

If you're willing to install additional third-party software, the [GNUWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) (GNUWin32) project offers Windows ports of a number of these utilities (commands).

The utilities themselves are offered in [packages](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) with either a single utility or several utilities bundled in each. Each package can be installed separately <sup>1</sup>, with the exception of certain packages where the included utilities are dependent on others.

The basic package you will most likely want to install is the [CoreUtils package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) but there are other packages available as well (depending on what utilities you may wish to use).

For what it's worth, I've included some simple example batch files using GNUWin32 utilities which may help you in another section of this answer.

**GNUWin32 Alternatives**

Setting aside the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) in Windows 10, there are other possible options for using these types of utilities on Windows, such as [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/) and [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

These versions often have the advantage of being more up-to-date than their GNUWin32 counterparts, but arguably may be lacking in ease of installation and use.

---

<sup>1</sup> *The GNUWin32 Project offers a download utility called [GetGnuWin32](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), which can handle downloading and installing all available GNUWin32 packages in one go (if that is your preferred option).*

**Notepad++**

I am personally not aware of any Notepad++ plugins or features that fully support what you're trying to accomplish. However, Notepad++ can run batch scripts, commands and executables directly via the Notepad++ *Run...* menu ( <kbd>F5</kbd> ) or the NppExec plugin and thus can be used (to some degree) in concert with e.g. GNUWin32 utilities.

With that said, I am not sure of a good mechanism for feeding separate open files as a group to anything listed above. One partial workaround is to combine the two files into one, sort them, save the file and then run a variation of the "Single File Output" example batch file given later in this answer against that saved file.

Notepad++ does support more low-level interactions with the editor via the [Python Script for Notepad++ plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) (based around a self-contained version of Python 2.7). Unfortunately, my experience with that plugin is limited so I am uncertain how it might be able to help you towards the desired functionality (if at all).

If you want to experiment with the Python Script for Notepad++ plugin yourself, you can install it under the *Plugins → Plugins Admin...* interface in Notepad++.

---

**GNUWin32 Batch Examples**

The batch (`.bat`) file examples given below leverage GNUWin32 utilities and are intended show some rudimentary approaches to (hopefully) accomplishing your goals. But they are simply references. They can almost certainly be improved upon or even ignored all together in favor of other approaches.

---

*These batch files assume the GNUWin32 [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) package is installed (for the `sort`, `uniq` and `comm` utilities). The example which uses `comm` also requires [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) (a separate package).*

---

For completeness, the following (minimal) text files were used as test input for the example scripts outlined below:

*ex. dup1.txt*

```
abc
def
123
ghi
```

*Unique Line:* `123`

**--**

*ex. dup2.txt*

```
ghi
abc
jkl
def
```

*Unique Line:* `jkl`

---

**Example Batch - Single File Output**

In conjunction with e.g. the GNUWin32 CoreUtils package, you can create a Windows batch file that supports dragging/dropping two text files onto it, then having the non-duplicated lines displayed as a third, single file opened in ex. Notepad++:

*ex. nodupes.bat*

```
@ECHO Off

@REM Two input files (paths)
gnu-sort %1 %2 | uniq -u > uniq_text.txt

@REM Check our command output.
:: PAUSE

START notepad++.exe uniq_text.txt
```

Note that in the example above, `gnu-sort` is the GNUWin32 `sort` utility, renamed to avoid conflicts in Windows (see the *Windows Conflicts* section).

---

*While this batch file can be used in a "drag and drop" mode for convenience, you can also pass the relevant file names directly at the command line e.g. `nodupes.bat dup1.txt dup2.txt`. This is true for the other batch examples in this section as well.*

---

**Example Batch - Single File Output (Notepad++)**

To achieve something similar more directly in Notepad++, you can create a new batch file similar to the one already described above but with a single input:

*ex. nodupes-npp.bat*

```
@ECHO Off

@REM One input file (path)
gnu-sort %1 | uniq -u > C:\path\to\uniq_text.txt

START notepad++ C:\path\to\uniq_text.txt
```

You would then save this `.bat` file in a static location for Notepad++ to reference. Then, in Notepad++ e.g. under the *Run...* menu ( <kbd>F5</kbd> ), you could invoke this batch file for whatever (single) file was currently open:

```
cmd /c C:\path\to\nodupes-npp.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

A couple caveats exist to this approach, however:

1) The current file open would need to be a combined version of the two files you wished to compare data from.

2) The file you wish to apply this to must be saved before using this `.bat`/*Run...* approach. This is because:

- `"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` isn't available in Notepad++ until the file is saved.
- If changes are made to the file, any updates need to be applied to the actual file being accessed (i.e. the version on disk, not the version currently open in Notepad++).

**Example Batch - Multiple File Output**

If you want unique lines divided (relatively) by their originating files, [you can instead use a combination of `comm` and `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336404/how-to-get-the-output-from-the-comm-command-into-3-separate-files):

*ex. nodupes-separated.bat*

```
@ECHO Off

@REM Use sed to divide our comm -3 output into two files,
@REM using a simple sed script (filter.sed).

gnu-sort %1 > sorted_duplicates_1.txt
gnu-sort %2 > sorted_duplicates_2.txt

comm -3 sorted_duplicates_1.txt sorted_duplicates_2.txt | sed -f filter.sed

@REM Check our command output.
:: PAUSE

@REM Clean up our temporary files.
DEL sorted_duplicates_1.txt
DEL sorted_duplicates_2.txt

@REM These file names are defined in ex. filter.sed
START notepad++ uniq_text_1.txt
START notepad++ uniq_text_2.txt
```

*ex. filter.sed*

```
/^\t/ {
    s///
    w uniq_text_2.txt
    d
}
/^[^\t]/ {
    w uniq_text_1.txt
    d
}
```

Note that while `comm` is part of the CoreUtils package, [sed is a separate download with GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). Keep in mind that the batch file above won't alter your original files, it will create two new ones (so renaming them is up to your). Also, as written, ex. `filter.sed` need to be in the same directory as your batch file (e.g. `nodupes-separated.bat`).

---

**Windows Conflicts (GNUWin32)**

GNUWin32 contains some utilities with same name as Windows utilities or commands (e.g. `sort`). This can present a (mild) issue, as each utility may operate differently. The conflicts I am personally aware of in the GNUWin32 CoreUtils package are:

- date
- dir
- echo
- find
- hostname
- sort
- whoami

---

*Keep in mind there may be other conflicts in separate packages as well, e.g. `tree`.*

---

If you want to access the GNUWin32 versions from your environment path (i.e. without typing their full path), you can either rename the appropriate GNUWin32 executables themselves (recommended) or use surrogate batch files whose names are different (less desirable). A surrogate batch file would simply contain e.g.:

*ex. gnu-utility.bat*

```
@ECHO Off
C:\path\to\GNUWin32\bin\utility.exe %*
```

**Using Windows Utility Versions**

You may be able to use the Windows version of a utility, but they can require reworking how you approach things. For instance, Windows `sort` by default can only take one input at a time, so the original `nodupes.bat` example above might look like the following when using it:

*ex. nodupes-win-sort.bat*

```
@ECHO Off

@REM Helps compensate for a minor issue with cat and newlines
ECHO. > blank

@REM Using Windows sort, not GNUWin32 sort
cat %1 blank %2 | sort | uniq -u > uniq_text.txt

@REM Clean up our temporary file.
DEL blank

START notepad++.exe uniq_text.txt
```

**Notes (GNUWin32)**

- For the GNUWin32 utilities to work without specifying a full path, you will want to add them to your environment path in Windows. Otherwise, you will need to specify full paths to each executable (be aware this may cause headaches ex. with piping).
- GNUWin32 packages are arguably best placed in a "regular" Windows folder you create (i.e. not `C:\Program Files`, `C:\Program Files (x86)` or your `User` folder).
- You should likewise try to install GNUWin32 into a path without spaces (e.g. `C:\Programs\GNUWin32`).
- While the GNUWin32 CoreUtils package supports a variety of basic tools, [there are still quite a number of utilities that are available as their own individual packages or groups of utilities](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html). Also, some utilities may work slightly differently or have more limited options/syntax simply because the underlying OS (Windows) is not e.g. Linux.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i needed. It not the answer I wanted, but i guess i'll have to deal with it. =)

Comment: Your welcome. Sorry the answer wasn't more helpful. For what it's worth, I've looked for tools or plugins similar to what you describe in your original question and have never had much luck either. Still, I appreciate the check mark. Thanks and good luck. =)