# How to delete all lines found in another txt document in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have two files, name it as target file and source file. I want to delete all the entries in the target file which are present in the source file. How to achieve this in notepad++.

Both target and source file have one column

Couldn't find anything similar

## Target File Content:

```
9048019c-cf28-4f33-bc67-e18dc1facc40
ef869420-2987-4e54-a1ea-3fe074b9a2cf
12622407-a7b1-4cbb-b83f-0b9631422527
824fb2cf-1c73-4f61-8687-6ccae090ffb5
9048019c-cf28-4f33-bc67-e18dc1facc40
07b433aa-c6d2-4699-809d-e094a20516be
be103490-370b-407b-b507-28238aadf661
824fb2cf-1c73-4f61-8687-6ccae090ffb5
4137e7aa-6b2b-49b1-b2d8-38f862d7c5e1
26844327-4b24-47d0-b421-0f2bedeba141
be103490-370b-407b-b507-28238aadf661
824fb2cf-1c73-4f61-8687-6ccae090ffb5
4c00e75d-f862-4011-a3d8-1cecc74a8cc7
a5bcaf38-413d-4ead-a5fb-1c75ecfe3b77
26844327-4b24-47d0-b421-0f2bedeba141
```

## Source File,

```
12622407-a7b1-4cbb-b83f-0b9631422527
07b433aa-c6d2-4699-809d-e094a20516be
4137e7aa-6b2b-49b1-b2d8-38f862d7c5e1
4c00e75d-f862-4011-a3d8-1cecc74a8cc7
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question IMO. Probably better to ask on SuperUser.

Comment: This is not a job for Notepad++, you'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Yeah I thinks that is the only option, just wondering if there is a way in notepad++. Thank you for checking this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++ Compare two files and remove](https://superuser.com/questions/562208/notepad-compare-two-files-and-remove) See this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1528207/214658